# How to use a different browser to run electron app instead of the electron browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

I am reverse engineering an electron application but in its code, it checks for the browser and limits the options to either Chrome 8.0 or Edge 8.0 or higher. Hence, instead of using electron browser for debugging, I want to use one of these, how can I go about doing so?

Comment: Is the implementation that you are looking for in Javascript or nodejs? If yes then you can easily extract the source code which is an ASAR archive.

Comment: @Asesh i have done that,  I am running the application too, just wanted to switch the browser from Electron 8.2 to chrome 80, currently I am doing this from the networks tab

Comment: I doubt you can do that. Electron uses their own version of Chromium's Blink, V8 and Nodejs. Even if you replace the necessary modules to do so, ABI compatibility issues might crash that app.